# System.InvalidOperationException : A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, xunit

Im Working .Net 6 with xUnit

I get when runnig tests

```
System.InvalidOperationException : A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed
```

this is my code:

```
public class MasterServiceTests : IClassFixture<RealDatabaseFixture>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IRepository<Master> _repository;
    private readonly IMasterService _masterService;

    private AddMasterDtoBuilder addMasterDtoBuilder;
    public MasterServiceTests(RealDatabaseFixture database)
    {
        _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(database._context);
        _repository = _unitOfWork.MasterRepository;
        _masterService = new MasterService(_unitOfWork);
        addMasterDtoBuilder = new AddMasterDtoBuilder();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Create_ShouldAddMasterToContext()
    {
        //arrange
        var master = addMasterDtoBuilder.Build();

        //act
        _masterService.AddMaster(master);

        //assert
        _repository.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == master.Email && c.PersonalCode == master.PersonalCode).Should().NotBeNull();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Create_ShouldNotAddDuplicatedEmailOrPersonalCode()
    {
        //arrange
        int personalCode = 1234;
        string email = "mahdi@gmail.com";
        var master = addMasterDtoBuilder
            .WithEmail(email)
            .WithPersonalCode(personalCode)
            .Build();
        _masterService.AddMaster(master);

        //act
        var actual = _masterService.AddMaster(master);

        //assert
        actual.Status.Should().Be(Darsyar.Application.Common.Models.ResultStatus.Duplictaed);
    }
}
```

Create_ShouldNotAddDuplicatedEmailOrPersonalCode() has error

In this RealDataBaseFixture I Used Transaction Scope and I Disposabled It
When run two AddMaster() give me error

Comment: Your `RealDatabaseFixture` may create a real database with seeded data, but you should create a `DbContext` per test.

Comment: Or don't run tests in parallel